# SSLSocket duplex close failed after SSL handshake

Tags: java, ssl

I'm using `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient` to connect send a GET request to remote service. During SSL handshake i get

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E5|http-94|2023-05-15 19:13:39.725 CEST|ECDHClientKeyExchange.java:407|Produced ECDHE ClientKeyExchange handshake message (
"ECDH ClientKeyExchange": {
  "ecdh public": {
    0000: 34 BE 01 2F CC BA EB 1B   71 DB 0F 21 69 97 4A 04  4../....q..!i.J.
    0010: 59 C8 62 B4 14 B1 C8 97   35 96 C8 5F D0 4E 2A 0C  Y.b.....5.._.N*.
  },
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E5|http-94|2023-05-15 19:13:39.728 CEST|CertificateVerify.java:767|Produced CertificateVerify handshake message (
"CertificateVerify": {
  "signature algorithm": rsa_pss_rsae_sha256
  "signature": {
    0000: 72 FD 57 75 C3 EA FC 30   E8 B9 E5 C5 8F 1F 5B 55  r.Wu...0......[U
    0010: C1 2E 97 27 7C 92 A7 12   5D 03 4C A9 EA A1 66 4C  ...'....].L...fL
    0020: 89 6B D9 2D C0 C6 75 20   CB 6D 14 B3 7B AB 3A 6E  .k.-..u .m....:n
    0030: 55 CA 45 18 7F AE 0F D6   46 50 3C 09 95 95 66 73  U.E.....FP<...fs
    0040: F8 16 AB E9 06 1D 6E 87   31 E8 E8 E8 1E CC 23 C5  ......n.1.....#.
    0050: 23 D9 49 90 B2 FE 2D 26   58 A7 E7 50 99 80 1B F6  #.I...-&X..P....
    0060: 67 BE 81 EE 98 06 23 4B   A1 2E B5 DC 4A 61 9E 27  g.....#K....Ja.'
    0070: 6C 16 1C 18 86 E7 D4 64   28 5E D1 F5 F0 E6 89 17  l......d(^......
    0080: 3C 26 EC 79 83 B3 B0 30   D4 EB 27 2E D3 FB 6D 3F  <&.y...0..'...m?
    0090: B1 C7 2C A6 3C 6E DB AA   68 5A B1 59 9E 48 C8 10  ..,.<n..hZ.Y.H..
    00A0: F8 89 DD E3 AA E3 85 15   9B 91 7F 62 FC EF D4 DF  ...........b....
    00B0: C1 1D CB 95 54 5F 4F 3C   68 0C 72 0B 2A ED B5 C5  ....T_O<h.r.*...
    00C0: 51 97 26 8D 64 8F 4F C7   DF 95 32 63 6E 00 55 66  Q.&.d.O...2cn.Uf
    00D0: 12 16 AF 50 DA 27 CF 71   75 AC BC 50 FC 70 11 13  ...P.'.qu..P.p..
    00E0: 53 80 AD 28 30 D2 D6 B1   93 3B 21 AB 10 22 EC 7E  S..(0....;!.."..
    00F0: 71 9F 52 CA 67 21 85 DA   F7 D0 BD 18 92 6D EA 40  q.R.g!.......m.@
  }
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E5|http-94|2023-05-15 19:13:39.728 CEST|ChangeCipherSpec.java:115|Produced ChangeCipherSpec message
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E5|http-94|2023-05-15 19:13:39.728 CEST|Finished.java:396|Produced client Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: B3 92 53 87 32 D4 33 31   06 1F F4 A2 
  }'}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E5|http-94|2023-05-15 19:13:39.736 CEST|ChangeCipherSpec.java:149|Consuming ChangeCipherSpec message
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E5|http-94|2023-05-15 19:13:39.736 CEST|Finished.java:548|Consuming server Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: E7 CC CF D2 3D 39 4F 1A   05 EA 05 F3 
  }'}
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E5|http-94|2023-05-15 19:13:39.744 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1134|Closing input stream
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E5|http-94|2023-05-15 19:13:39.744 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:577|duplex close of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E5|http-94|2023-05-15 19:13:39.744 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1754|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E5|http-94|2023-05-15 19:13:39.744 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1780|close the SSL connection (initiative)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E5|http-94|2023-05-15 19:13:39.745 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:833|close inbound of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E5|http-94|2023-05-15 19:13:39.746 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:595|SSLSocket duplex close failed. Debug info only. Exception details: (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.shutdownInput(Socket.java:1601)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:219)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:848)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.bruteForceCloseInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:798)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.duplexCloseOutput(SSLSocketImpl.java:660)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.close(SSLSocketImpl.java:584)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.close(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.close(BufferedInputStream.java:481)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.MeteredStream.close(MeteredStream.java:177)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.MeteredStream.justRead(MeteredStream.java:95)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:142)
        at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3663)
        at org.apache.cxf.helpers.IOUtils.copyAtLeast(IOUtils.java:250)
        at org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.WireTapIn.handleInputStream(WireTapIn.java:91)
        at org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.WireTapIn.handleMessage(WireTapIn.java:61)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientMessageObserver.onMessage(ClientMessageObserver.java:56)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1701)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1570)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1371)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.close(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:77)
        at org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingOutputStream.postClose(LoggingOutputStream.java:53)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:228)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:671)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.doRunInterceptorChain(AbstractClient.java:710)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:1086)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:932)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:901)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:461)
        at ch.logobject.ti.bl.NNI.recuperaInstradamentoPdr(NNI.java:371)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at ch.logobject.as.ejb.StatelessHandler.invokeAuthenticated(StatelessHandler.java:514)
        at ch.logobject.as.ejb.StatelessHandler.invokeWithCl(StatelessHandler.java:404)
        at ch.logobject.as.ejb.StatelessHandler.invokeNow(StatelessHandler.java:327)
        at ch.logobject.as.ejb.StatelessHandler.invoke(StatelessHandler.java:316)
        at ch.logobject.ti.bl.NNI$ByteBuddy$Ro4y31JO.recuperaInstradamentoPdr(Unknown Source)
        at ch.logobject.ti.bl.TIProjectManagement.recuperaInstradamentoPdr(TIProjectManagement.java:20234)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at ch.logobject.as.ejb.StatelessHandler.invokeAuthenticated(StatelessHandler.java:514)
        at ch.logobject.as.ejb.StatelessHandler.invokeWithCl(StatelessHandler.java:404)
        at ch.logobject.as.ejb.StatelessHandler.invokeNow(StatelessHandler.java:327)
        at ch.logobject.as.ejb.StatelessHandler.invoke(StatelessHandler.java:316)
        at ch.logobject.ti.bl.TIProjectManagement$ByteBuddy$y3XwgfB0.recuperaInstradamentoPdr(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at ch.logobject.common.jms.beanbridge.GenericBeanInvoker.invoke(GenericBeanInvoker.java:87)
        at ch.logobject.common.jms.beanbridge.EntityBeanInvoker.invoke(EntityBeanInvoker.java:40)
        at ch.logobject.common.jms.beanbridge.SessionBeanBridge$1.invoke(SessionBeanBridge.java:261)
        at ch.logobject.common.jms.beanbridge.SessionBeanBridge$1.invoke(SessionBeanBridge.java:1)
        at ch.logobject.common.mdb.CallWithRetry.call(CallWithRetry.java:218)
        at ch.logobject.common.jms.beanbridge.SessionBeanBridge.processRequest(SessionBeanBridge.java:314)
        at ch.logobject.common.jms.beanbridge.SessionBeanBridge.processRequest(SessionBeanBridge.java:171)
        at ch.logobject.common.jms.http.BridgeServlet.jmsRequest(BridgeServlet.java:211)
        at ch.logobject.common.jms.http.BridgeServlet.doPost(BridgeServlet.java:155)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:179)
        at ch.logobject.as.jetty.StatsHandler.handle(StatsHandler.java:34)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:555)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:410)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:164)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)}

)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E5|http-94|2023-05-15 19:13:39.761 CEST|SSLEngineImpl.java:425|trigger NST
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|E5|http-94|2023-05-15 19:13:39.761 CEST|NewSessionTicket.java:446|Produced NewSessionTicket post-handshake message (
"NewSessionTicket": {
  "ticket_lifetime"      : "86,400",
  "ticket_age_add"       : "<omitted>",
  "ticket_nonce"         : "02",
  "ticket"               : {
    0000: 98 E6 C6 65 19 1C 25 1C   F8 64 CE 99 B2 F1 57 F1  ...e..%..d....W.
    0010: 73 7E 25 89 F5 6D F7 58   52 B0 45 F9 7E 0F E7 9E  s.%..m.XR.E.....
  }  "extensions"           : [
    <no extension>
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|E5|http-94|2023-05-15 19:13:39.761 CEST|SSLEngineImpl.java:825|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|E5|http-94|2023-05-15 19:13:39.762 CEST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:182|outbound has closed, ignore outbound application data
```

I have the full dump of the ssl debug if needed.

EDIT: changed formatting, thanks for comment.
EDIT: tried some curl and openssl command to narrow the problem

OpenSSl: `openssl s_client -connect URL -tls1_2 -status -msg -debug -CAfile cert.cer`

```
SSL handshake has read 2742 bytes and written 350 bytes
Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 2EF81214C3C914886F4AC9AEFB57368596819E2171F1E61073F12D0823B534B5
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: B08FBAE4DAE96955255D53ABA4E07D03528B67BE0A66416307FF2E6454BA42BD65A22DEA82ABC630F4B56168A9EA9BFF
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1684180040
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
    Extended master secret: yes
```

Curl:  `curl --tlsv1.2 --tls-max 1.2 --verbose --cacert  cert.crt 'URL'`

```
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OBFUSCATED
*  start date: Jan 12 08:06:58 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 12 08:06:58 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "OBFUSCATED" matched cert's "OBFUSCATED"
*  issuer: OBFUSCATED
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55fbed1356b0)
 GET OBFUSCATED HTTP/2
 Host: OBFUSCATED
 User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
 Accept: */*
 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
 HTTP/2 200 
 date: Mon, 15 May 2023 19:49:42 GMT
 content-type: application/json
 x-content-type-options: nosniff
 x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
 cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
 pragma: no-cache
 expires: 0
 strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
 x-frame-options: DENY
```

Curl gives Positive output (the service answer correctly), is the only way is working.

Comment: Use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for logs, not quote format. Quote is for human text, not logs and other pre formatted text. Quote breaks the existing format of the log, makes it very hard to read and gets in the way of trying to copy text for investigation.